# How to make a web app using flutter and integrate twillo vedio chat api?

Tags: twilio, flutter-web

I have a very old client who wants me to make website for him where I have to integrate a twilio vedio chat api.The thing is I'm a native android developer so it will be very easy for me to jump on flutter but the thing is I'm not sure if it's possible for a flutter made website to use twilio vedio chat api.So my question is what I'm wanting is it really possible?

Comment: It all depends on use cases like if you plan to target one code base for multiple platform like windows and macos. Flutter web is still in beta. While there are several examples and clones of major sites being made to show off the power of flutter UI framework its still not recommended to use for heavy duty applications. Its safe to rely on time tested technologies. What you can do is maybe keep the UI logic abstracted away and replace it when flutter becomes mainstream.

Comment: thanx, I have a same thought  and appreciate your suggestion